# Regex Expresion Regular que permita solo # positivos separados por coma o guion JS

Tags: javascript, regex

he tomado de algunos post estas regex me dan error en el archivo JS, talvez me hace falta agregarle un cierre son estas:

`^[0-9,-]*$;`

`^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?$;`

`^-?\d+(?:,\d+)?$;`

estos son los escenarios correctos para guardar:

**2,3,6,9-11 //CORRECTO**

estos son los escenarios que busco validar y no permita guardar:

**2,3,,6 //Repeticion de comas INCORRECTO**

**2,2,6 // Repeticion del mismo numero, INCORRECTO**

**6, ,69 ,6, // Espacios ya sea entre comas o un numero, INCORRECTO**

**9--11 //Repeticion de guiones, INCORRECTO**

cual de las 3 validaciones es la recomendable y que es lo faltante en la regex?

Comment: explica por favor lo de los números repetidos, si no bastaría con algo como `^-?\d+(,\d)*$`

Comment: Vas a necesitar más de una RegExp. Necesitas una para validar formato y otra para validar contenido (_caso `2,2,6`_). Si me baso en el titulo de tu pregunta solo estas pidiendo la primera. Considera agregar mas ejemplos de correcto/incorrecto. Para los siguientes casos cual debería ser el resultado: `2,2-3,9` (_2 repetido?_), `2,3-2-9,4` (_mas de un -#_), `2,,` (_dos comas_), `2,,3` (_dos comas y #_), `9--` (_dos guiones_), etc.

Comment: tu misma pregunta a copilot me responde `^[0-9]+ (,|- [0-9]+)*$`

Answer (score 0):

No se me ocurre como validar solo con regex lo siguiente:

```
2,2,6 // Repeticion del mismo numero, INCORRECTO
```

De cualquier forma, es más facil cambiar a un enfoque usando regex y código js.

---

Obtenemos cada número con el método split. Usamos de separador la regex `[-,]`, es decir, guion o coma. Por ejemplo, para el caso `1-2g--,,3`, obtendrías un array así `["1", "2g", "", "", "", "3"]`. Las cadenas vacías representan una repetición del separador.

Una vez hecho esto, aplicamos la regex `^[0-9]+$` a cada "numero" obtenido. Dicha regex matchea con una cadena que solo tenga caracteres del 0 al 9 y mida al menos un caractér. Si no machea, significa que el numero es incorrecto.

Para validar que no se repitan números, parseamos números validos con parseInt y los guardamos en un Set. Si un número en la cadena ya está en el set, significaría que fue emcontrado anteriormente.

Esto, llevado a la practica, queda como:

```js
function validator(string){
    let numeros = new Set()

    for(let num of string.split(/[-,]/)){
        if(num.match(/^[0-9]+$/) === null){
            console.log("invalido:", num)
            return
        }

        num = parseInt(num)
            
        if(numeros.has(num)){
            console.log("repetido:", num)
            return
        }

        numeros.add(num)
    }
}

console.log("1-2g--,,3")
validator("1-2g--,,3")

console.log("")

console.log("1-2--,,3")
validator("1-2--,,3")

console.log("")

console.log("1,3-2,3")
validator("1,3-2,3")

console.log("")

console.log("1-2,3")
validator("1-2,3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría la siguiente expresión regular para validar los números separados por comas o guiones

```
^\d+([,\-]\d+)*$
```

Y finalmente para chequear que no se repite ningún numero, la siguiente expresión regular **no** se debería cumplir:

```
^(\d+[,\-])*(\d+)[,\-](\d+[,\-])*\2([,\-]\d+)*$
```